# Can I define a domain root for links in GitHub pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am creating a user guide for my web app using GitHub pages in the web app's repo.

I want to have links in the user guide to the appropriate pages in the web app. I can hard code the entire thing. But I'd prefer to set the app domain in one place and then use that domain for all urls.

So something like:

```
ROOT_DOMAIN=MyApp.com
```

And then in the markdown have `[Login](%ROOT_DOMAIN%/account/login)`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The short answer is "yes", but you have (1) "config file + markdown data" which you (presumably) feed into (2) "some software you have written which builds a website out of 1" and then (3) publish on GitHub pages. We know absolutely nothing about 2 — not even what programming language you've written in it! — so I'm not sure what sort of answer you are expecting.

Comment: If you're using Jekyll, the default static site generator for GitHub Pages, you're looking for the `baseurl` setting (see [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options)); it lives in `_config.yml`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes - that's perfect. If you make your comment an answer I'm happy to the accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default static site generator for GitHub Pages is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), and it lets you configure the repository base URL in `_config.yml` via the `baseurl` setting; see the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options):

| Setting | Options and flags |
| --- | --- |
| **Base URL** Serve the website from the given base URL. | `baseurl: URL` `-b`, `--baseurl URL` |

where `-b`/`--baseurl URL` is the command line option for the `jekyll` command, and `baseurl: URL` is the YAML config setting.